# Which is the best way to implement SOAP Web Services on JBoss Seam?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, seam

I need to implement a SOAP Web Service on Jboss Seam 2.1.0. The idea is to export an Stateless bean method as a Web Service.

However, I have found two approaches.

- First one, is to use the Seam's own web services annotations. The problem of this is the lack of documentation.
- Second one, is to use Enunciate. It's a lot better documented, but I feel that this is not the standard manner.

So, which one is the best approach? Have I missed something? Is there more documentation around about the JBoss Seam "standard" SOAP web services implementation?

Thanks in advance, regards,
(Sorry, as I'm new here, I cannot post hyperlinks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used JAX-WS which works very well with EJB3.  Annotate your stateless bean with `@WebService`, your methods with `@WebMethod` and your parameters with `@WebParam`.

The only trick to getting it to work with Seam is if you need authentication.  In that case I've defined a `SOAPHandler` in `standard-jaxws-endpoint-config.xml`.  You'll need to pull the username and password information out of the SOAP header and manually authenticate with Seam.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I also have found some examples of that on the Seam distribution. I will test the authentication part.