# Webservice using Seam

Tags: web-services, seam

I am new to Seam and want to develop Webservice using Seam.I have an aggressive deadline Where i can find the details to develop the Webservice using Seam.Any good document, book, website etc.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911424/which-is-the-best-way-to-implement-soap-web-services-on-jboss-seam

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911424/which-is-the-best-way-to-implement-soap-web-services-on-jboss-seam) you could use JAX-WS. However if you'd rather use REST services (JAX-RS) then either:

- Read up on JAX-WS in the [Seam Docs](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/webservices.html)
- Check out Stéphane Épardaud's article
  [here](http://blog.lunatech.com/2008/03/20/restful-web-services-java-ee-resteasy-jax-rs); or
- Have a look at Sun [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) which is an implementation of JAX-RS.

**EDIT**: Norman Richards from the Seam team has just posted a [blog article about Seam and JAX-RS](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/RESTSupportInLatestSeam21). Looks fantastic and probably more what you are after than Jersey.

I had a look at Jersey last week and was amazed at how little code you need. Here's a little guide:

1. Download the Jersey Jars and the
   JAXB Jars (so you can output XML
   and/or JSON) and add them to your classpath
2. Add the Jersey servlet to your
   web.xml (in the example below with a `url-pattern` of `service/*`)
3. Annotate the Bean that holds your
   data with JAXB annotations
4. Create a Service class with the
   Jersey annotations.

Here's an example of a Service:

```java
@Path("/users")
public class UsersService {
  @GET
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
  public Users getUsers() {
    return UserQuery.getUsers();
  }
}
```

Where this is the Users class:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
public class Users {
  @XmlElement(name="users")
  private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
  }

  public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
  }
}
```

And this is the User class:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
  @XmlElement(name="id")
  private long userId;

  @XmlElement(name="firstName")
  private String firstName;

  @XmlElement(name="lastName")
  private String lastName;

  @XmlElement(name="email")
  private String email;

  public User() {}

  public User(long userId, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
  }

  //And the getter/setters
}
```

Then you can access the service at **`http://yourhost/service/users`**
It will produce XML or JSON depending on what your client has for it's HTTP Accepts header. Pretty cool huh?